# AutoHotKey: remapping Alt+Shift+Tab to (L)Win+Shift+Tab

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, windows-key

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows to have the same behavior as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in macOS.

Note: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on a mac keyboard sends the <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

What I've gotten to work is:

```
LWin & Tab:: AltTab
```

What I haven't been able to do is get <kbd>LWin</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.  I've tried:

1. `#Shift & Tab:: ShiftAltTab` (error: must specify L or R for # in this case)
2. `LWin & Shift & Tab :: ShiftAltTab` (Can't use 3 custom combinations)
3. ```
   Lwin & Tab::
          if GetKeyState("Shift")
              {
              Send {ShiftAltTab}
              }
          else
              {
              Send {AltTab}
              }
   ```

I also tried with return lines after each `Send` line. Nothing happened when pressing either

- <kbd>LCmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (== <kbd>LWin</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) or
- <kbd>LCmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (== <kbd>LWin</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Is there a quick and simple way to do this? I want to use AHK since it is modifying the combinations to mimic a lot of other Mac keyboard behaviors.

Answer (score 9):

```
LWin & Tab:: 
    AltTabMenu := true
    If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
        Send {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}
    else
        Send {Alt Down}{Tab}
return

#If (AltTabMenu)

    ~*LWin Up::
        Send {Shift Up}{Alt Up}
        AltTabMenu := false 
    return

#If
```

Tested on Windows 10.

Comment: Does it work on your system?

Comment: Yes, it does work

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Taking the answer given by @user3419297 even further, since it worked only for the left modifiers:

```
LWin & Tab:: 
RWin & Tab:: 
    AltTabMenu := true
    If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
        Send {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}
    else
        Send {Alt Down}{Tab}
return

#If (AltTabMenu)
    ~*LWin Up::
    ~*RWin Up::
        Send {Shift Up}{Alt Up}
        AltTabMenu := false 
    return
    RShift::LShift
#If
```

This allows both Win and Shift modifiers to be used interchangeably.